# NHibernate - are stored procedures executed immediately or only on commit?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate. Say I call a stored proc using Session.GetNamedQuery().UniqueResult() inside a transaction. Does NHibernate execute the SP immediately or only when I call the commit() on the transaction? If it happens immediately does it also update the object in session accordingly with the changes from execution of the SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will execute SP immediately. The best way to find the answer and to play around with NH is to write an unit test to verify its behaviours. You can find the skeleton unit test project and guide here: 
[The best way to solve NHibernate bugs? Submit good unit test](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/10/03/the-best-way-to-solve-nhibernate-bugs-submit-good-unit-test.html)